# Ежедневные уведомления в определенное время даже если приложение закрыто или устройство было перезагружено

Tags: java, android, уведомления

Пытаюсь реализовать ежедневные оффлайн уведомления/напоминания (строго в определенное пользователем время). Пробовал через AlarmManager, но у него недостаток - если приложение принудительно закрыть или устройство перезагрузить, уведомление перестанет приходить. WorkManager вроде как не может отправлять уведомление в указанное время.
У кого есть опыт в этой теме, расскажите как это реализовать. Желательно на Java. Заранее благодарен.

Comment: нужно ловить сообщение BroadcastReciever BOOT_COMPLETED и устанавливать AlarmManager заново.

Comment: @Style-7 пробовал, что-то не получается. Есть ли у Вас какой-нибудь рабочий пример? Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `Manifest` добавляем:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

// Чтобы "ловить" перезагрузку, выключение
<receiver android:name=".receiver.BootCompleteReceiver"
   android:enabled="false">
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>

// Чтобы "ловить" смену времени
<receiver android:name=".receiver.TimeChangedReceiver">
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>

// Наши уведомления
<receiver android:name=".receiver.NotificationReceiver" />
```

`BootCompleteReceiver`:

```kotlin
class BootCompleteReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        if (intent.action == Constants.BOOT_COMPLETED) {
            AlarmsUtility.setAlarm(context)
        }
    }
}
```

`TimeChangedReceiver`:

```kotlin
class TimeChangedReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        if (intent.action == Constants.TIME_SET) {
            AlarmsUtility.setAlarm(context)
        }
    }
}
```

`NotificationReceiver`:

```kotlin
class NotificationReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    private lateinit var notificationManager: NotificationManagerCompat

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context)

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
           createNotificationChannel()
        }

        var text = "Уведомление"

        val builder = getNotificationBuilder(context).setContentText(text)
        notificationManager.notify(Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build())
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private fun createNotificationChannel() {
        val channel = NotificationChannel(
            Constants.NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID,
            Constants.NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME,
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
        )

        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }

    private fun getNotificationBuilder(context: Context) =
        NotificationCompat.Builder(context, Constants.NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
            .setContentTitle(null)
            .setContentText(null)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_EVENT)

}
```

`AlarmsUtility`:

```kotlin
object AlarmsUtility {
    fun setAlarm(context: Context) {
        val hour = 12 // Час уведомления, можно брать с настроек
        val minute = 0 // Минуты уведомления, можно брать с настроек

        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance().apply {
            timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
            set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour)
            set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute)
        }

        val broadcastIntent = Intent(context, NotificationReceiver::class.java)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, broadcastIntent, 0)

        val alarmManager = context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        alarmManager.setRepeating(
            AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            calendar.timeInMillis,
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
            pendingIntent
        )
    }

    fun cancelAlarm(context: Context) {
        val broadcastIntent = Intent(context, NotificationReceiver::class.java)
        val pendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, broadcastIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE)
        val alarmManager = context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent)
    }
}
```

Я в манифесте поставил `BootCompleteReceiver = false`, чтобы включать его самостоятельно из кода, и отключать когда уведомления выключены:

```kotlin
val bootCompleteReceiver = ComponentName(requireActivity(), BootCompleteReceiver::class.java)

if (...) {
   requireActivity().packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
      bootCompleteReceiver,
      PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
      PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
   )
   AlarmsUtility.setAlarm(requireContext())
} else {
   requireActivity().packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
      bootCompleteReceiver,
      PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
      PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
   )
   AlarmsUtility.cancelAlarm(requireContext())
}
```

Думаю тоже самое необходимо прописывать для `TimeChangedReceiver`. Не уверен, более опытные подскажут.

*Извиняюсь за качество написанного кода и изложения своих мыслей.*

Comment: Благодарю. Также очень желательно из приложения попросить пользователя включить автостарт приложения и отключить "умный режим" который может убить ваше приложение